# pymodm can't find an object, while pymongo successfully finds it

Tags: python-3.x, pymongo, pymodm

I have a problem getting an object from the `mongodb` instance. If I search for this object with `pymongo` interface, everything is fine - object can be found. If try to do the very same thing with `pymodm` - it fails with error.

Here is what I'm doing:

```
from pymodm import connect, MongoModel, fields
from pymongo import MongoClient


class detection_object(MongoModel):
    legacy_id = fields.IntegerField()

client = MongoClient(MONGODB_URI)
db = client[MONGODB_DEFAULT_SCHEME]
collection = db['detection_object']
do = collection.find_one({'legacy_id': 1437424})
print(do)

connect(MONGODB_URI)
do = detection_object.objects.raw({'legacy_id': 1437424}).first()
print(do)
```

The first print outputs this: `{'_id': ObjectId('5c4099dcffa4fb11494d983d'), 'legacy_id': 1437424}`. However, during the execution of this command: `do = detection_object.objects.raw({'legacy_id': 1437424}).first()` interpreter fails with the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymodm/queryset.py", line 127, in first
    return next(iter(self.limit(-1)))
StopIteration

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/konsof01/PycharmProjects/testthisfuckingshit/settings.py", line 29, in <module>
    do = detection_object.objects.raw({'legacy_id': 1437424}).first()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymodm/queryset.py", line 129, in first
    raise self._model.DoesNotExist()
__main__.DoesNotExist
```

How can this be? I'm trying to query the very same object, with the same connection and collection. Any ideas, please?

Answer (score 0):

you could try it as follows:

```
detection_object.objects.raw({'legacy_id': "1437424"} ).first()
```

probably the `legacy_id` is stored as string.

Othewise, make sure the db name is present at the end of the `MONGO_URI` as it is underlined in the [docs](https://pymodm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting-started.html#connecting-to-mongodb).

Answer (score 0):

Each document in your 'detection_object' collection requires to have '_cls' attribute. The string value stored in this attribute should be

```
    __main__.classname
```

(class name according to your code is detection_object).

For example a document in your database needs to look like this:

```
    {'_id': ObjectId('5c4099dcffa4fb11494d983d'), 'legacy_id': 1437424, '_cls': '__ main __.detection_object'}
```